# MailChimp form in iFrame, how to configure the "return to our homepage" link?

Tags: wordpress, iframe, hyperlink, parent, mailchimp

I have a WordPress site, and in one page I have an iFrame which loads a MailChimp form. After completing the form and submitting the info, I have the option from MailChimp to return to your homepage, but when I click the link it just loads my entire site in the iFrame.
Is it possible to load the page in the main window when I click the link? I know I would have to have the attribute target="_parent" on the link, but how do I add that in MailChimp?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Just do complete this old post with a possible solution: adding this little javascript on the page that mail chimp calls at the end will do the job

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
         // iframe breakout for mailchimp
         if(this != top){
         top.document.location.href = this.document.location.href;
    }
    </script>
```